# How to include a navbar with directives in Angular?

Tags: angular

Is there a "correct" way to add navbar's to your Angular application? I have a 3 component app, where I would like all of the pages to show a navbar at the top of. I would like this navbar to include Angular Router links and toggle it's appearance based on user logged in or not. If I just stick the following code into my app.component template, then the pages loose their angular functionality. I am, not sure why this happens, but I can see why that approach is not good.

```
<div class="nav">
    <a [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a>
</div>
```

Do you create a separate component, or is that overkill? Just looking if there is any conventional wisdom, otherwise, just for a working solution. (I don't think that is too subjective, but I guess you'll let me know if it is ;) ).

## Update:

So here is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';

import {TodoService} from './todo/services/todo.service';
import { TodoCmp } from './todo/components/todo.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    //here is where I tried the navbar
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['client/dev/todo/styles/todo.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [
    TodoService,
    UserService
  ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'TodoCmp',
    component: TodoCmp,
    useAsDefault: true
  }
  //other paths
])

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng2do';
}
```

and this is how it renders, as the code above shows:

[image]

and then if I add the navbar code with angular references:

[image]

Alternatively, if I create a Nav.Component, with selector `nav-bar`, then I can change my app.component template from:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

to:

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

but with this approach the nav bar doesn't seem to render at all and the other component displays as normal?

Comment: That's not a lot of information. Can you create a Plunker ([template](https://plnkr.co/edit/wnLWAW?p))`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was kinda hoping for a general answer, of how you would compose a navbar in an ng2 app, [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Gen-App/tree/master/client/dev) is my source code, can happily make a plunker if that would help?

Comment: It would be better to show what you actually try to accomplish, ideally with some code and what issue (error, behavior, ...) you run into with your approach. Every developer has different requirements.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sure, I have shown the issue I am running into with adding links in the app.component, stopping the todo component rendering

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer No I am not

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar must be in the app component while the route component are injected in router-outlet. You should have a look at the following Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ekkB3F?p=info. The root component is the following.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
  <a [routerLink]="['Login']" *ngIf="login">{{login}}</a>
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <input [(ngModel)]="login" type="text"/>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        component: LoginComponent,
        name: 'Login',
        path: '/login',
    }
    ])
export class App {
  login:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
  }

}
```